# Rosenbrock function with D dimension using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I implement the **Rosenbrock function** with D dimension, using PyTorch?

> Create the variables, where `D` is the number of dimensions and `N` is the number of elements.

```
x = (xmax - xmin)*torch.rand(N,D).type(dtype) + xmin
```

> Function :

[image]

> Using straight Python I'd do something like this:

```
fit = 0
for i in range(D-1):
    term1 = x[i + 1] - x[i]**2
    term2 = 1 - x[i]
    fit = fit + 100 * term1**2 + term2**2
```

> My attempt using Pytorch:

```
def Rosenbrock(x):
    return torch.sum(100*(x - x**2)**2 + (x-1)**2)
```

> I just do not know how to do the `x[i+1]` without using a for loop. 
>   How can I deal with it? 
>   Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy has the function `roll` which I think can be really helpful.
Unfortunately, I am not aware of any function similar to `numpy.roll` for pytorch.

In my attempt, `x` is a numpy array in the form `DxN`. First we use `roll` to move the items in the first dimension (`axis=0`) one position to the left. Like this, everytime we compare `x_1[i]` is like if we do `x[i+1]`. Then, since the function takes only `D-1` elements for the sum, we remove the last column slicing the pytorch tensor with `[:-1, :]`. Then the summation is really similar to the code you posted, just changing `x` for `x_1` at the correct place.

```
def Rosenbrock(x):
    x_1 = torch.from_numpy(np.roll(x, -1, axis=0)).float()[:-1, :]
    x = torch.from_numpy(x).float()[:-1, :]

    return torch.sum(100 * (x_1 - x ** 2) ** 2 + (x - 1) ** 2, 0)
```

Similarly, by using `roll` you could remove you for loop in the numpy version